# GWT question on RPC

Tags: gwt, gwt-rpc

I'm trying to understand the RPC functionality which GWT uses, and have followed this [guide](http://lkamal.blogspot.com/2008/09/java-gwt-servlets-web-app-tutorial.html). It works perfectly OK if I follow the guide and has the call to the server in a separate class file. However when I try to have the call where the entryPoints creates it will not work.

I wonder why it is like that and how to fix it?

```
package com.async.me.client;

import com.async.me.client.widgets.HelloWidget;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.EntryPoint;
import com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent;
import com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickHandler;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Button;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.RootPanel;

/**
 * Entry point classes define <code>onModuleLoad()</code>.
 */
public class Async_test implements EntryPoint {

    private Button specialButton = new Button("Special");

    private DataServiceAsync service;
    public void onModuleLoad() {
        // set widget on "content" element
        RootPanel content = RootPanel.get("content");


        content.add(specialButton);
        service = (DataServiceAsync) GWT.create(DataService.class);
        specialButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                System.out.println("Sometihng");

                service.getData(new AsyncCallback() {

                    public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
                        System.out.println("Server call failed");
                    }
                    public void onSuccess(Object obj) {
                        System.out.println("Success");
                        if (obj != null) {
                            System.out.println(obj.toString());
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("Server call returned nothing");
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here's the error trace

```
16:43:22.768 [ERROR] [async_test] Uncaught exception escaped

com.google.gwt.event.shared.UmbrellaException: One or more exceptions caught, see full set in UmbrellaException#getCauses
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:214)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:101)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.fireEvent(Widget.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(DomEvent.java:116)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onBrowserEvent(Widget.java:151)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventImpl(DOM.java:1308)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(DOM.java:1264)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:326)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:207)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:126)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:214)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor22.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:281)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:531)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.ServiceDefTarget$NoServiceEntryPointSpecifiedException: Service implementation URL not specified
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RemoteServiceProxy.doPrepareRequestBuilderImpl(RemoteServiceProxy.java:326)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.RemoteServiceProxy.doInvoke(RemoteServiceProxy.java:265)
    at com.async.me.client.DataService_Proxy.getData(DataService_Proxy.java:35)
    at com.async.me.client.Async_test$1.onClick(Async_test.java:44)
    at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:54)
    at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.ClickEvent.dispatch(ClickEvent.java:1)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.doFire(SimpleEventBus.java:204)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.SimpleEventBus.fireEvent(SimpleEventBus.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.event.shared.HandlerManager.fireEvent(HandlerManager.java:101)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.fireEvent(Widget.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.event.dom.client.DomEvent.fireNativeEvent(DomEvent.java:116)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget.onBrowserEvent(Widget.java:151)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEventImpl(DOM.java:1308)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.DOM.dispatchEvent(DOM.java:1264)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:326)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:207)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:126)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:269)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:214)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor22.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:157)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessages(BrowserChannelServer.java:281)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:531)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your code did not set the service endpoint, as indicated by the nested exception.  These are the lines in the tutorial that do that:

```
service = (DataServiceAsync) GWT.create(DataService.class);
ServiceDefTarget endpoint = (ServiceDefTarget) service;
endpoint.setServiceEntryPoint(GWT.getModuleBaseURL() + "data");
```

Study those lines and the rest of the example to see how the GWT RPC call maps to invoking the needed servlet and then add the necessary equivalent to your code (it should be pretty much the same).

However, the newer GWT uses a more convenient annotation now (`@RemoteServiceRelativePath("stockPrices")`) to set the service endpoint.  See:

http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html

Comment: Simple fix, fixed it. Thanks! :)