# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException on GWT async class in webapp

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, asynchronous

I am developing a webapp using GWT. When I try to run it under eclipse ("Run as web application"), I get a java.lang.ClassNotFoundException pointing to my RPC async class.

I am experienced with development in Java but not with GWT. I did research this issue but the advice I found did not work for me, or I did not know how to apply it to my own webapp. I am hoping someone will be able to provide some insight.

#### The error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:gov.nist.toolkit.xdstools3.server.InterfaceClientServerImpl
--- stack trace of some more Jetty and GWT stuff that fails because of the error above ---

javax.servlet.UnavailableException: gov.nist.toolkit.xdstools3.server.InterfaceClientServerImpl
--- same thing ---
```

#### My implementation

I implemented the RPC logic:

```
client > InterfaceClientServer
       > InterfaceClientServerAsync
server > InterfaceClientServerImpl
```

and modified the web.xml to point to my service class.

#### InterfaceClientServer.java

```
package gov.nist.toolkit.xdstools3.client;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteService;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteServiceRelativePath;

@RemoteServiceRelativePath("service")
public interface InterfaceClientServer extends RemoteService {
    public void logMeIn(String username, String password);
}
```

#### InterfaceClientServerAsync.java

```
package gov.nist.toolkit.xdstools3.client;

import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.AsyncCallback;
import com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.RemoteServiceRelativePath;

public interface InterfaceClientServerAsync {

    public void logMeIn(String username, String password, AsyncCallback<Void> callback);
}
```

#### InterfaceClientServerImpl.java

```
package gov.nist.toolkit.xdstools3.server;

import com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet;
import gov.nist.toolkit.xdstools3.client.InterfaceClientServer;

public class InterfaceClientServerImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements InterfaceClientServer {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void logMeIn(String username, String password){
        Caller.getInstance().logMeIn(username, password);
    }
}
```

#### web.xml

```
    <web-app>
    <display-name>Document Sharing Toolkit</display-name>

    <!-- Default page to serve -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Xdstools3.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!-- Example servlet loaded into servlet container -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>InterfaceClientServer</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>gov.nist.toolkit.xdstools3.server.InterfaceClientServerImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>InterfaceClientServer</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/xdstools3/service</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

#### Main tutorial I used

http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html

#### Similar issues

I also found a few similar issues on Stackoverflow, such as this one: [GWT question on RPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907827/gwt-question-on-rpc). This post would suggest that something is wrong with my web.xml and the linking to the async class, but I could not figure out what.

#### Other technologies used and versions

In case it ends up being relevant: GWT 2.5.1, Maven (m2e), Smartgwt.

Any help will be very welcome.

Comment: Hi Darkane, What are you trying to do? Are you running the code through eclipse or what?

Comment: Hi, yes, I run the code under eclipse as a Web application and I get the errors above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server side classes may not be compiled.

Please ensure server side classes are present under `target`. Check your project's class-path also.

---

Please confirm from below screenshots:

- WAR directory `src/main/webapp`
- Launch and deploy from this directory is unchecked
- Default output folder `project/target/classes`

[image]

[image]

Comment: That's it. My Java Build Path pointed to a different compile folder. My app being called xdstools3, my output folder was "xdstools3>target>classes". But my configuration actually needed the version information to match my Maven build, so the correct output path was for me "xdstools3-v***>target>classes". With that change, my app runs fine. Thank you!

Comment: Actually, the issue came back shortly after. One of my colleagues experienced the same thing on GWT Maven Eclipse projects that otherwise had worked fine at some point. Eclipse being notoriously buggy when it comes to Maven projects, and having frequent refresh issues as well, we are examining the possibility that an underlying issue could be a bug in that area maybe caused by our specific combination of Maven and GWT modules. We also discovered that transitioning to the IDEAJ editor fixes things without any changes to our code.

Comment: Yes it happens whenever you do a maven update project. It goes back to its default settings. Just validate it again and change it again after every maven update.